# Django urls.py regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, django

I completed the Django beginner tutorials and I am trying to complete the [The Django Book: Chapter 7 Forms][1]. I am having an issue getting the URLSconf to link to the search_forms.html page using the methodology in the documentation. Most likely because I am using separate 'main' and 'app' urls.py files

Can anyone help me with the right format for the URLconf? I want to see the search_forms.html page when i visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/search-form/`

I have a main urls.py file located at /src/project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),   
)
```

I also have a polls urls.py located at /src/polls/urls.py You can see I have tried a few solutions.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),


    #this one will bring me to the vote page when i type search-form in the browser
    #http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/2/search-form/
    #url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/search-form/$', views.vote, name='search-form'),


    #url(r'^/search-form/$', views.search_form, name='search_form'),

    url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form),

    #url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/search-form/$', views.search_form, name='search-form'),

    #url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form),
    #url(r'^$', views.search_form, name='search-form/$'),  
   # url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/detail_dropdown/$', views.vote, name='detail_dropdown'),
)
```

I have a search_form.html page located at /src/polls/templates/polls/search_form.html with the same code from the tutorial

I also have the search_form view set up at src/polls/views.py with the below code

```
def search_form(request):
    return render(request, 'search_form.html')
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit: Browser Error Message**

Thanks @Ailistar

I have tried it with the uncommented url, this is the error message.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/search-form/

search_form.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/search-form/
Django Version:     1.6.2
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

search_form.html

Exception Location:     /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 131
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/Users/brendan/Dropbox/workspace/bias_experiment/src',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/yolk-0.4.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-4.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 28 Apr 2014 20:36:43 +0100

  [1]: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html
```

Comment: Surely it's obvious from the error message that this isn't a problem with the regex, but with the template?

Comment: Only if you know that is the right regular expression to use. Which Alasdair confirms that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uncommented url in your question should work. It's good practice to name it.

```
url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form, name="search_form"),
```

The error message explains what the problem is.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/search-form/

search_form.html
```

You have put your template in "polls/search_form.html", but in your view, you are using the template "search_form.html".

To fix the problem, you can either change the view to

```
return render(request, 'polls/search_form.html')
```

Or you can move the template into the parent directory `/src/polls/templates/`.

If the url pattern above does not work, then please update your question to say what error you get when you go to `/polls/search-form/` in your browser.

Comment: I thought so too.

Error message added. Thanks

Comment: I had to use the second option and move the file into the parent directory. The change view option did not work, out of interest have you any idea why?

Comment: Changing the view should work. You haven't given enough information to tell why it didn't. I'm glad the second option worked for you.